# Cannot access to image file(s) after upload SpringMVC

Tags: spring-mvc, file-upload

I got stuck when access the resource after upload it using spring-mvc upload.

The path I store the file(s) is:

```
@Autowired
ServletContext context;
....
private File path(String fileName){
    return new File(context.getRealPath("/upload/images/")+fileName);
}
...//mkdirs before uploading the file(s)
```

So after mkdirs() method called, on the temp folder to run app in apache-tomcat server has one new folder nearby resources folder named as above (upload).

The upload method I created has successful upload the file(s) to that folder.
And I can access that file with the same solution like above.

But in jsp file, I cannot access to the image file(s) I uploaded to that path.
See the code below:

```
<%File item = (File)request.getAttribute("imageFile");%>
...//some conditions to validate the file
<img class="myprev-img" src="upload/images/<%=item.getName() %>" width="100%" height="100%">
```

I cannot get the image by the code above, but in normal jsp and servlet application, that code can read the image from the local. But in SpringMVC I cannot access to that image.

So any solutions to access the image file(s) from local uploaded by the same method like me.

I've search around and I do not see any solutions to help me this.

please help me!!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to solve my problem. See the link below:

```
http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources
```